# Very slow boot after cloning system to a larger disk

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, lubuntu

I have Lubuntu 18.04 LTS i386 installed on an SD card on Intel Classmate PC laptop.

I have recently cloned the 16GB card to a 64GB one using Win32DiskImager and resized it using GParted LiveUSB.

The boot is absurdly slow now, and I have looked around and tried all the solutions but it seems the problem lies somewhere in GRUB, but I'm kinda fresh to Linux so I don't know here to start looking to identify it.

I disabled splash to see the kernel boot messages and found out the boot is stalling for exactly 2 minutes (120 seconds) in grub, before loading the kernel (with blank screen, no cursor), which would suggest some kind of a timeout event, but I don't know where to start looking for the cause behind it.

So far I tried solutions form other similar questions:

- `/etc/fstab` shows the correct UUID for disk (matching `blkid` one)
- `blockdev --getalignoff /dev/sdb1` shows `0`
- `swap` is a file, not a partition
- `/etc/crypttab` doesn't exist
- `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d` is epmty
- I ran `update-grub`
- I ran `update-initramfs -uk all`
- `systemd-analyze` doesn't account for the entirety of boot time
- `dmesg` shows nothing interesting, as boot messages only start showing up after 2 minutes of grub limbo

It seems the stall is somewhere in grub. I have checked to make sure that `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` shows UUID matching `blkid` one everywhere. `/var/boot.log` is empty `journalctl -b` starts at the same point `dmesg` does (after 2 minutes)

Any ideas as to where I could start looking to identify the problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the other SD card used? and thus you have two or more volumes with the same UUID (*which is a problem*), are you using *swapfile* or *swap partition*? (*swap partitions usually aren't resized, but deleted & re-created which can change UUID*).  I have assumed BIOS and not UEFI given you've mentioned x86, is this correct?

Comment: No, it's just the new SD card, the old one is retired. And yes, it's BIOS, not UEFI. I'm using swapfile (at /swapfile, listed without UUID in /etc/fstab ).

Comment: Run `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and `systemd-analyze blame` to see what part of the boot tha takes the time.

Comment: `systemd-analyze` shows 30 seconds total boot time, whereas the entire boot takes over 2 minutes. Whatever happens happens inside grub / boot, before kernel loads, but I don't know how to debug that

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the reason behind this.

I typed `set debug=all` in grub console which allowed me to trace down everything that happens and loading initial ramdisk is what's the slowest. Here's why.

In non-uefi mode GRUB needs to load initrd kernel image from disk using BIOS commands, switching in and out of protected mode to read every block. This plus SDXC card latency creates a lot of lag when reading the kernel image. Kernel image is over 60MB in size and GRUB is configured to load it by smaller chunks in BIOS mode by default to avoid running out of memory. Here is the GRUB bug associated with this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/944347

The smaller card was simply a tad faster, not by much but GRUB lazy loading scheme amplified the difference by far.